# NIS client is not able to change password using yppasswd?

Tags: opensuse, nfs, nis

NIS Server - OpenSuse 12.1

NIS Clients - OpenSuse 13.2

At NIS Client:

```
nisuser@opensuse13.2:~> yppasswd
yppasswd is deprecated, use /usr/bin/passwd instead
Changing password for nisuser.
Old Password:
New password:
Re-enter new password:
Error: Password NOT changed
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

But NIS Client which runs on OpenSuse 12.1 is able to use `yppasswd` successfully. Changes NIS user password successfully!

P.S. `yppasswdd` is running on NIS master.

Any suggestions?